# SASS compact property syntax in Stylus

Tags: stylus

is it possible to do something like

```
background:
  image: url(...)
  repeat: no-repeat
  size: cover
```

which is possible in SASS to be done in Stylus?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not possible in stylus. But you could use a function like this:

```
background($url, $repeat = false, $size = false, $position = false, $attachment = false)
    background-image url($url)
    if ($repeat)
        background-repeat $repeat
    if ($size)
        background-size $size
    if ($position)
        background-position $position
    if ($attachment)
        background-attachment $attachment
```

and use it like this: `background("../images/ico-timeline.png", repeat-x, auto, center left, fixed)` or `background("../images/ico-timeline.png", repeat-x, auto)`.

The variables marked as `false` are optional, so you don't need to use it everytime you use this function.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in Stylus.